# Is there any way to make a method with more than one instance?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber, bool onlineOffline)
        {
            if (onlineOffline == false)
            {
                OffLineDownload.offhtmlfiles();
                page = OffLineDownload.OffLineFiles[offLineFileNumber];
                byte[] bytes1 = File.ReadAllBytes(page);
                page = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).GetString(bytes1);
                TextExtractor.GetDateTimeList(page);
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\" + htmlFileName);//@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
                w.Write(page);
                w.Close();
                extractlinks.Links(@"C:\Temp\" + htmlFileName);
                TextExtractor.ExtractText(@"C:\Temp\" + htmlFileName, newText);
            }
            else
            {
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
                page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
                TextExtractor.GetDateTimeList(page);
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
                w.Write(page);
                w.Close();
                extractlinks.Links(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
                TextExtractor.ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html", newText);
            }
        }
```

If the user calls the method I want him to have two options to call it with all 3 variables:

```
string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber, bool onlineOffline
```

Or to call it without the variables and if it's () so it will be automatic true.

Comment: There are various ways to achieve this.

Overloaded methods or optional parameters.

In the original version of C#, optional parameters were not supported and some think that overloaded methods are better, due to a clearer "contract" between the caller and the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "overload" the method.  Have the same name with multiple parameter signatures.

```
private void Extractions()
{

}
```

Since your method is a "void", I don't know what you mean by " if it's () so it will be automatic true."

Unless what you meant was:

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber)
{
     Extractions(htmlFileName, offLineFileNumber, true);
}
```

Of course you could also just make the offLine paremeter optional and give it a default of true.

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber, bool onlineOffLine = true)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: A method without parameters is a property.  You could create a property called Extractions that is a boolean, that always returns false.  But that would be confusing to me.  Methods and Properties are different in fact and in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional arguments to achieve what you want :

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName="", int offLineFileNumber=0, bool onlineOffline=true)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Then you can call your method with required parameters, something like :

```
Extractions("myfile.txt", 1, true);  // or
Extractions("myfile.txt", 1)
```

Comment: A little more explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called method overloading.

Just define your method multiple times, with different parameters

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber, bool onlineOffline)
{
  //All your logic here
}
```

Overloaded method:

```
private void Extractions(string htmlFileName, int offLineFileNumber)
{
// Call the main method, passing true
Extractions(htmlFileName, offLineFileNumber, true);
}
```

See here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx